# GeoFencing on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps, geofencing

I am using GeoFencing to set a region and perform some task when user Enters or Leaves the region. Bt it is not working for me, i am using gollowing code

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(some values,some values);
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:15.0 identifier:@"SF"];
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
```

But None of the delegates **didEnterRegion** and **didExitRegion** being called when i close the application and the app is monitoring and i move away from that region or enter.

Comment: what do you mean with close?? send to background via home button, or terminate the app? A terminated app does not run.

Comment: it wont get called immediately, there is a buffer distance in which it will still not trigger a notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a radius of 15m. That is too small. First, try with 50m or more. Look at the map app, if you really have entered that region.
Furthermore, I hope you meant "send to background", instead of closing.
make sure you have set your app to be allowed to run in background? (via plist)

**Update:**

Finally it turned out that you terminated the application. Then of course you will not get any loctaion events anymore.
Solution: 
Don't terminate it via double click on home button follwed by selecting the white cross, simply close it with one click on home button, then it has chance to run in background.

**Update2:**
Even when the app was terminated, ios relaunches it when it has registered to the location monitoring service:
from [CllLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

> If you start this service and your application is subsequently
>   terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into
>   the background if a new event arrive...

Comment: I have allowed the application to run in the background that is working fine. and i completly closed the application, doesn't Geofencing works when the applciation is completely closed? I can see GeoFencing icon in status bar and in settings.

Comment: Do you zclose it via double click on home button, and the clicking on the cross? This is terminate, then nothing of your app is running. This is not background!

Comment: :) yes i do terminate the application. soo is there a way to wake my app automatically when a user enters a region?

Comment: No, but if you leave it in background it is woke up automatically by apple. So simply do not terminate it, and if a user terminates it, then it should be not working anymore.

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary feel free to upvote / accept, since your question is now answered.

Comment: Need to ask one more thing does iphone reminder app only works when it is running in the background?

Comment: All Apple apps can do what it wants, running hidden etc. But the applications not created by apple have to follow their concept. A terminated App is always terminated, except it is an apple app, then evrything is possible.

Comment: @AlexWien: that seems to directly contradict what Apple says in the CLLocationManager documentation which says: 

    "In iOS, the regions you register with the location manager persist between launches of your application. If a region crossing occurs while your iOS app is not running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in the background so that it can process the event. When relaunched, all of the regions you configured previously are made available in the monitoredRegions property of any location manager objects you create."

Comment: @AlexWien: Although I'm not entirely clear on what "relaunching" the application looks like. Does it send you a application:didFinishLaunching:? That would be odd since that's typically where you setup the initial view controller. On the other hand, you couldn't assume in another callback that everything is setup that you might need...I'm hopefully going to be testing this out this weekend, so I'll try to get back with what I find out.

Answer (score 1):

Add CLLocationManagerDelegate in header file. 
make sure u added

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

try increasing the radius and check.

Comment: Yes i have done that. Does radius has be be alot more like more than 100?

Answer (score 1):

First of all increase the radius you are giving for that particular location and check again if it does not work then by following some easy steps provided in this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift) you can easily implement Geo-Fencing in your app.

Reference: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)

Answer (score 0):

You define a radius of 15m. That is too small. First, try with 50m or more. Look at the map app, if you really have entered that region.
Furthermore, I hope you meant "send to background", instead of closing.
make sure you have set your app to be allowed to run in background? (via plist)